# DevExpress GridControl BestFit | AutoSizeMode?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, xtragrid

I have 4 Dev Express Grid Columns (Two are not visible) 
I'am trying to make the visible Columns like :

```
this.DataGridView1.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
```

I tried the following :

```
 gridView2.Columns["MyColumnB"].BestFit();
```

It works fine but is there is anyway so It dosen't get Width more then GridControl and don't get that Horizental ScrollBar ?

**Sorry , Fixed using :**

```
 gridView2.OptionsView.ColumnAutoWidth = true;
```

Comment: And you get your answer?

Comment: Yes , I solved it using the code that I posted after editing

Comment: OK, then post your solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code which will tell the grid view to never display the horizontal scroll bar, then create the best fit columns for the entire grid view, instead of just doing so for a specific column.

```
gridView2.HorzScrollVisibility = ScrollVisibility.Never;
gridView2.BestFitColumns();
```